# How to add a comma to this javascript output?

Tags: javascript

Here is my counter:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.count').each(function () {
      $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
          Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
          duration: 4000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function (now) {
              $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
          }
      });
  });
  </script>
```

And I thought that adding this might insert a comma after the first digit:

```
      (1234567890).toLocaleString();
```

This could work but not sure how to merge it into the above:

```
function addCommas(nStr)

    {
        nStr += '';
        var x = nStr.split('.');
        var x1 = x[0];
        var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;
    }
```

Any ideas how to edit this?

Comment: `$(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString())`?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working example

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
  const regex = /\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
  return num.toString().replace(regex, ',');
}

console.log(formatNumber(1));
console.log(formatNumber(100));
console.log(formatNumber(1000));
console.log(formatNumber(1000000));
```

Comment: Thank you @jank but I ended up using the suggestion above, just had to tweak one line of code

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)?

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN').format(1234567890));
```

Comment: Thanks - in fact I just ended up using >>>>> $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString())  <<<< which seems to have worked great...